# Spring Kafka: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Kafka messages are consuming normally.
But I get this error intermittently.

```
Exception:org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:206) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2377) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2254) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2300(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:518) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$3.doInTransactionWithoutResult(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2092) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36) \~\[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20\]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) \~\[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2083) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2052) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2028) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1704) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1275) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1267) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1162) \~\[spring-kafka-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14\]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) \~\[?:?\]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) \~\[?:?\]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) \~\[?:?\]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnOffsetCommitHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1732) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:1290) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:586) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:578) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:415) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:313) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240) \~\[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar!/:?\]
```

Why is this error occurring?
There is no problem in consuming Kafka messages.

Sorry.
I speak a little English.
So the question is awkward.

Comment: Are you sure there's no problem? Looks like the consumer group rebalanced, so as the error says, the group coordinator doesn't know about that instance anymore, therefore cannot commit the transaction. Add a rebalance listener

Answer (score 0):

Is this exception causing any issues in your consuming application? This exception is most likely a warning, not an error so it shouldn't terminate the consumer. However, depending on your offset reset policy, you may be missing messages or you could have duplicates.

What has most likely happened is that one of the consumers has shut down and another has joined the group to replace it. As the error says, the coordinator is not yet aware of the new consumer so a rebalance needs to happen so the new consumer is assigned a fair share of the partitions.

As mentioned above, I would check if you are missing messages / have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened for us as well, it's an error and it does not recover.
We had to restart the application for it to work again.

Our case was, the Kafka brokers started a rolling restart to update certificates, which leads to loads of issues in the cluster, but usually it recovers except for some timeouts.

We use the confluent kafka operator.

This has only happened once, but it happened in production so it kinda hurts..

Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:1125)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.sendOffsetsToTransaction(TransactionManager.java:420)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1149)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doSendOffsets(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2816)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2807)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitOffsetsIfNeeded(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2187)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2161)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$1900(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:553)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2048)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2039)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2021)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2003)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1257)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnOffsetCommitHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1771)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:1322)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:583)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:418)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```